# Why is multibinding supported in WPF, but not silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, multibinding

Multibinding is a pretty powerful feature in WPF, why is it not supported in silverlight?
They never got around to adding support to it?  It's too big to fit in the .NET framework?  Will it be coming in Silverlight 5? Anyone know the answers?

Thanks!

Comment: ASP.NET tag has nothing to do with your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not supported out of the box, but you can throw together an approximation that will maybe do what you want: look [here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/05/silverlight-multibinding-solution-for-silverlight-4/) and [here](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/08/silverlight-multibinding-updated-adding-support-for-elementname-and-twoway-binding/)

Microsoft has a good page on [what's coming up in Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/future/) but no mention of multibinding.

Comment: Thanks, I have read each of those links.  I hope Microsoft decides to incorporate that code in SL5, even though there is not mention of it, as you say.

Comment: BTW - How'd you end up getting a job in Japan :D?

Comment: I've been training as a Ninja since birth, it was only natural :)

Comment: Haha - Hey if you write a blog entry about that, I promise to read it.  doumo arigatou gozaimasu, ninja-san.