# How can you bind 2 properties on checkbox on silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I want to use 2 properties on binding the value of checkbox when loading.
This is what I have currently:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkIsAssigned" 
 IsChecked="{Binding IsAssigned, Mode=TwoWay}" 
 VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
 Click="chkParticipantUser_ToggleCheck" />
```

I want to do something like IsChecked="{Binding Property1 Property2}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MultiBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=netframework-4.8) is not supported in Silverlight, but there are some third-party [attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6099569/259206) to implement it externally.

In your case, looking simple enough, your best bet would be to create a property in the ViewModel combining the value of the two properties on get and setting the value to the two properties on set.